# Laravel: check if value were pass to the view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How can i check if value is passed to the view? 
for example

```
return View::make('view', array('result' => $result))->withInput(Input::flash()); or
return View::make('view')->with('result', $result)->withInput(Input::flash());
```

how can i check in the view if $result is pass.

I already tried

```
@if(Session::has('result')) and @if(Session::get('result'))
```

but it always gives me false or no value

Comment: I found a solution @if(isset($result))

Comment: That was my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the variable directly:

```
@if(empty($result))
```

Comment: I was trying to check if this route pass a 'result' value, because this 'view' were used by two routes.. one have the 'result' value and the other don't

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are familiar with php, you may use  to check whether it is null.
2. Otherwise if you just want to display the result, simply type $result to check if the value is passed into the view.

   Please correct me if I got your question wrong.

Comment: so every route that calls that 'view' need to have 'result'? because this 'view' were called by two routes, the first one doesn't have the 'result' and the other have the 'result'.